# Accesing internal web server running Node.js

Tags: node.js, local-network

I have two laptops on a WiFi. One has XP (192.168.2.100) and one has Peppermint Linux (192.168.2.106). Both connect to the internet through a WiFi router (192.168.2.1). Peppermint has a Node.js webserver running which I can see when I run localhost:8000. I am able to ping and ssh from the XP-laptop to the Peppermint-laptop. Now I must be able to see the webserver in XP when I use the IP-address with the right port (ie: 192.168.2.106:8000), but nothing is happening. Could it be the port (8000) is closed on the XP-laptop? I also tried port 9000 which says "listening", but to no avail.

Any help is appreciated!

edit: To test if the setup is correct I installed Apache and voila, it works! But the question remains, what do I need to do to be able to reach the Node.js web server from the XP-laptop?

Comment: Is the server set to run on 127.0.0.1?

Comment: Yes it is, locally I can reach it using 127.0.0.1 and localhost.

Comment: Would you mind posting the code you are using for the server? It is hard to offer help otherwise. Your issue is most likely that you specified the server to run at 127.0.0.1, so that means you are only able to access it from that machine.

Comment: You Sir are a genius! I changed the address to the IP-address of the laptop and now it works on the XP-laptop as well! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Odds are your issue is that you specified a hostname when listening on the server. [According to the documentation:](http://nodejs.org/docs/v0.4.12/api/http.html#server.listen)

> server.listen(port, [hostname], [callback])
>
> Begin accepting connections on the specified port and hostname. If the hostname is omitted, the server will accept connections directed to any IPv4 address (INADDR_ANY).